# After rowedit the value should be affect the db and also it should be displayed in the datatable

Tags: java, jsf

I am very new born babie for Datatable. I use roweditor. But the problem is, the value is it not displaying after an edit was made in some rows. Sometimes the database was not changed as well. I use update query. Can anyone  help me?

Thanqu in advance.

```
here is my code:


public void onRowEdit(RowEditEvent event)
{
System.out.println("hello...");

detail_li.clear();
FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("row Edited",selected_bean.get_name());// i have doubt here

FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);

 DBQuery db = new DBQuery();
 String code=selected_bean.getCode();
String Student_name = selected_bean.getStudent_name();
 System.out.println(" code$..."+code);
String Student_name = selected_bean.getStudent_name();

 String rank = selected_bean.getRank();
String feedback = selected_sngbean.getFeedback();
int res = db.special_code(rank,feedback,code);//here used update query
 detail_li = db.detaillist(class,code,student_name);
}

     This is my datatable code..


     <h:form id="for1">
     <p:growl id="msgs2" showDetail="true"/>
     <div>
     <p:dataTable id="s" var="sn"  value="#{songdet.song_li}"  editable="true" style="font-size: 80%" selectionMode="single" selection="#{songdet.selected_sngbean}" rowKey="#{sn.track_no}" >


     <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{home.onRowEdit(event)}"  update="for1:msgs2"  process="for1"/>

     <p:ajax event="rowEditCancel" listener="#{home.onRowCancel(event)}" update=":for1:msgs2" process="for1"/>  




     <p:column headerText="Name" >
     <p:cellEditor>

     <f:facet name="output">
     <h:outputText value="#{sn.name}" />
     </f:facet>
     <f:facet name="input"> 
     <p:inputText id="modelInput" value="#{sn.name}" style="width:100%"/
     </f:facet>
     </p:cellEditor>
     </p:column>


     <p:column headerText="Age" >
     <p:cellEditor>
     <f:facet name="output">
     <h:outputText value="#{sn.age}" />
     </f:facet>
     <f:facet name="input">
     <p:inputText id="modelInput2" value="#{sn.age}" style="width:100%"/>
     </f:facet>

     </p:cellEditor>
     </p:column>

     <p:column headerText="class" >
     <p:cellEditor>
     <f:facet name="output">
     <h:outputText value="#{sn.class}" />
     </f:facet>
     <f:facet name="input">
     <p:inputText id="modelInput3" value="#{sn.class}" style="width:100%"/
     </f:facet>

     </p:cellEditor>
     </p:column>


     <p:column headerText="Rank" >
     <p:cellEditor>
     <f:facet name="output">
     <h:outputText value="#{sn.rank}" /> 
     </f:facet>
     <f:facet name="input">
     <p:inputText id="modelInput55" value="#{sn.rank}" style="width:100%"/
     </f:facet>
     </p:cellEditor>
     </p:column>

     <p:column headerText="feedback" >
     <p:cellEditor>
     <f:facet name="output">
     <h:outputText value="#{sn.feedback}" />
     </f:facet>
     <f:facet name="input">
     <p:inputText id="modelInput6" value="#{sn.feedback}" style="width:100%"/>
     </f:facet>
     </p:cellEditor>
     </p:column>




     <p:column style="width:50px;height: 20px" >
     <p:rowEditor  />
     </p:column>

     <p:dataTable>
     </div>
```

Comment: Unless you think we can read minds, you need to post your code here :-)

Comment: Thanqu Rohit for quick response...plz help me bro..

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31803791/pdatatable-rowedit-doesnt-update-row-object

Comment: i m using <p:datatable> not <h:datatable>

Comment: please reformat your code. Do not use 'quote' tags (the > in front) and use correct indentation.

Comment: sorry bro .. i tried a lot..i dono how to do it... i have found error in in rowedit action event

Comment: FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("row Edited", selected_sngbean.get_name());

Comment: whenever i click the editor it randomly choose the other name,it not take the perfect name which i m selecting.kindly check and inform.how to do it..Thanks for advance.

Comment: *"i m using <p:datatable> not <h:datatable>"*. So? You think to outsmart us without actually trying/following the solution/advice? Why are you asking us for help then?

Comment: oh both <p:> and <h:> are same ah?? brother dont get anger i dono tat too..

Comment: i will try and let you know..kindly help me...

Comment: broth BalusC kindly guide me...first explain me how to get the selected name after i click the event...whether i should put my event under post construct

Comment: Please format the post correctly. Everything is unnecessarily quoted.

Comment: ya i did some how ,remove unnecessarily quoted..please check now..

Comment: i didnt get any solution till now...

Comment: Thanks friends i got the solution.... i m happy... i did through java itself.... :) :)

Comment: Thanks greatly those who respond.... :) be in touch..

Answer (score 0):

```
 public void onRowEdit(RowEditEvent event) {
      int z;
       System.out.println("the selected row is....."+table.getRowIndex());
   z=table.getRowIndex();
   check(z);
    FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Row Edited",check(z));

     FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
}

  public String check(int i){
     String rank=""; 

     String Feedback="";
     String name="";

      int q;
     q=i;
      sBean st=new sBean();
       st=(sBean) student_list.get(q);

       name=st.getname();
        roll=st.getcode(); 


        DBQuery db = new DBQuery();



    int res = db.update(name,roll,rank);



    return rank;    





    }
```